# Regex para não escapar apenas < > =?

Tags: regex

Atualmente tenho o seguinte regex:

```
"/([^\w\.\,]+\s*)/"
```

Ele escapa, letras, números, vírgulas e pontos seguidos ou não de espaço. Como faço para deixar ele escapar tudo, exceto os caracteres: `<` `>` `=` `!`

Comment: Vc quer que case somente os caracteres `< > = !` isso?

Comment: Sim, apenas esses caracteres, seguidos ou não de espaço

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente isso, fará com que ele aceite somente os caracteres `<` `>` `!` `=`:

```
/[<>=!]/g
```

Exemplo: https://regex101.com/r/eF5pG8/1

Já isso fará com que ele aceite tudo exceto os caracteres `<` `>` `!` `=`:

```
/[^<>=!]/g
```

Exemplo: https://regex101.com/r/eF5pG8/3

Comment: Funcionou, assim também (que fiz de acordo com sua resposta anterior) `[(<|>|=|!)]`.

Comment: Parênteses e `|` dentro de colchetes são tomados literalmente, não como sintaxe especial. Essa regex também não aceita `(`, `|` nem `)`. Se você quer negar um conjunto de caracteres, faça simplesmente `/[^<>=!]/g`. P.S. E a do comentário do @LeonardoVIlarinho aceita `(`, `|` e `)` quando não devia aceitar.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, você tem rezão, não tinha me atentado a isso. Editarei a resposta com sua sugestão. Obrigado.